# Bootstrap 4 Not Styling After Upgrade

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that was written with Bootstrap 3.7 which I'm trying to get upgraded to Bootstrap 4.3.  I'm also using jquery, jquery UI and jquery Unobtrusive/Validate.

Functionally, it appears that everything is working and I have verified that all of the files running on the site (css and js) are the latest versions by going into the page source, right-clicking and opening each  and  reference.  All of the drop downs and autocompletes, etc. are functional.

The problem is that it looks like a bunch of Bootstrap styles are not properly being applied, specifically, but not limited to dropdowns, the Navbar and some other basic things. I'm getting this,
[image]

instead of this:
[image]

Again, I want to stress, everything is functioning, this is a styling problem.  This is what is rendering in my page, note all of the listed references are to local files and all have been verified to be the latest versions.
[image]

FWIW, if this helps
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"
                  ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/umd/popper.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ecm").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/ecm.js"));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

From Bootstrap 3 to 4, the are some differences in use, especially in classes.

For example, to keep a navbar fixed in version 4, you use `.fixed-top` or `.fixed-bottom`. You're still using `.navbar-fixed-bottom`.

The same for its color style. There is `.navbar-inverse` in your navbar, but in version 4 it is `.navbar-dark`.

To check the rest of your code, I recommend this source: [Differences Between Bootstrap 3 & 4](https://www.quackit.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_4/differences_between_bootstrap_3_and_bootstrap_4.cfm)

Comment: I found the same and thanks for the link!  Someone should tell Bootstrap to mix in a little lube for their next major update, I'm going to be walking funny for a week!